# query impossible for me?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 2 columns `a` and `b` with a 1:n relation:

```
A.id, a.text, a.b_id(fk), a.value --
B.id(pk), b.text etc
```

I want to create a query that returns the number of `b.id` with `count(a.value=1) > 0`

I tried this:

```
Select count(b.id)
from a.id
join b on a.b_id=b_id
group by b.id
having count(if(a.value=1),1,null))>0
```

...but without result. It seems simple but for me is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `HAVING` because standard `INNER` join won't return `b` rows without matching `a` rows anyway. You don't need `GROUP BY` either - use `COUNT(DISTINCT )` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS cnt
FROM b
JOIN a ON a.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.value = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableB AS B
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA
             WHERE id = B.id
             AND value = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Select count(b.id) as x
FROM b
JOIN a ON a.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.value = 1
group by b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplification on [@MarcinJuraszek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580493/query-impossible-for-me/18580537#18580537). If the foreign key can be trusted, there is no need to join table `b`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.b_id) AS cnt
FROM a
WHERE a.value = 1 ;
```